# How to use OR in Django Tastypie

Tags: mysql, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

Hi my project works on Django framework and AngularJS. What I want to achieve is once the user login, their status changes to 1, if he is department 1; 2 if he is under department 2 and so on. The problem is some of the department id is 01 instead of 1. Because of this in AngularJS part

```
$scope.dept = '{{ dept }}';
$scope.update_personlist = function(){
    console.log('Stage1: Loading Persons..... ');
    personresource_url.get({pm_id__startswith: $scope.dept},
        function(data){
            $scope.personlist = data['objects'][0]['person'];
            console.log($scope.personlist);
        },function(data, status){
            console.log('hi');
        }
    );
};
```

But this code will only return dept value 1, 2 etc instead of 01. Is there anyway we can do something like `personresource_url.get({pm_id__startswith: $scope.dept} OR pm_id__startswith: $scope.those startwith zero}`? Means, if the dept 1 person logged in he could able to see both dept1 and dept 01 persons. Can some one help? Am quiet new to Tastypie and AngularJS.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Dept "1" the same as "01"?  If so, you should [canonicalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) your database. i.e., when the data comes in, put it into one and only one format.  If 1 is not 01, then maybe you need an extra field (`dept_group` ?) to indicate which department rows belong to a group.

Comment: Rogers, Can't modify the database and the format. Thats the probelm here

Comment: Well, I'm sure there's a way to query `001` or `01` or `1` when fetching from TastyPie.  I use Django Rest Framework though, not TastyPie.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite your hydrate function to achieve this:

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):
    if bundle.data['dept'][0] == "0":
        bundle.data['dept'] = bundle.data['dept'][1:]
    return bundle
```

This way, it will only be saved without the leading "0"